# hash using multiple array value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

How I'm trying to build a hash for the following input

```
[["Company", "Add"], ["Company", "Edit"], ["Company", "Delete"], ["Company", "List"], ["Caterer", "Add"], ["Caterer", "Edit"], ["User", "Add"]]
```

The output should be

```
[{'Company'=>['Add', 'List', 'Edit', 'Delete']},
 {'Caterer'=>['Add', 'List', 'Edit', 'Delete']},
 {'User'=>['Add']}]
```

Try 1:

```
input = [["Company", "Add"], ["Company", "Edit"], ["Company", "Delete"], ["Company", "List"], ["Caterer", "Add"], ["Caterer", "Edit"], ["User", "Add"]]
a=[]
input.each do |inp|
  tmp = Hash.new
  a<< tmp.update(inp[0] => inp[1])
end
```

result:

```
[{"Company"=>"Add"}, {"Company"=>"Edit"}, {"Company"=>"Delete"}, {"Company"=>"List"}, {"Caterer"=>"Add"}, {"Caterer"=>"Edit"}, {"User"=>"Add"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Share your efforts please.

Comment: What happened to "Create"? Could it be that your output is not matching because the input is also wrong?

Comment: @Зелёный check my result and from that is it possible to group key and values?

Comment: @FerdinandRosario yep, use `group_by { |x| x.keys.first }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
result={}
[["Company", "Create"], ["Company", "Edit"], ["Company", "Delete"], ["Company", "List"], ["Caterer", "Create"], ["Caterer", "Edit"], ["User", "Add"]].each do  |value|
   result[value[0]]=[] unless result.has_key? value[0]
   result[value[0]] << value[1]
end
puts result.to_s

{"Company"=>["Create", "Edit", "Delete", "List"], "Caterer"=>["Create", "Edit"], "User"=>["Add"]}
```

But is not an array of hashes

If you still want to get a array you could do this

```
r=result.map{|k,v| {k=>v} }
```

Comment: `Caterer` key is wrong, as like `Company`. `{"Company"=>["Create", "Edit", "Delete", "List"], "Caterer"=>["Create", "Edit"], "User"=>["Add"]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
input = [["Company", "Add"], ["Company", "Edit"], ["Company", "Delete"], ["Company", "List"], ["Caterer", "Add"], ["Caterer", "Edit"], ["User", "Add"]]

as_hash = input.group_by(&:first)
as_hash.each do |entity, actions|
  as_hash[entity] = actions.flatten.reject do |action|
    action == entity
  end.sort_by { |action| ['Add', 'List', 'Edit', 'Delete'].index action }
end
```

**EDIT**: I just saw that you want an array of the pairs, instead of a hash. You can do that by:

```
as_hash.map { |pair| Hash[*pair] }
```

Comment: same as below, output is differ with OP, also it's create a `hash`, but OP required an array of hashes

Comment: anyway, `{"Company"=>["Add", "List", "Edit", "Delete"], "Caterer"=>["Add", "Edit"], "User"=>["Add"]}` it's not the same as OP wanted. **`Caterer` is wrong.**, also it create an **one hash**, but OP wanted, an array of hashes.

Comment: @Зелёный, fixed. Thanks again!